# Indefinite integral

Tags: complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

I want to integrate $\frac{1}{(1+x^4)}$ from zero to infinity, set $z_0,z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$ to be the roots of: $1+x^4$
Using Cauchy integral formula, on which path I should integrate?

Comment: Definite integral!

Comment: @jim it is an indefinite integral

Comment: You have asked for the integral of $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$ between two limits($0$ and $\infty$), which means you are calculating a definite integral?

Comment: No, it is an improper definite integral.  The indefinite integral would be an antiderivative $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry is your friend.  This integrand is symmetric under the rotation $z \to i z$, so you might try going from $0$ to $+\infty$ along the real axis and coming back in along the positive imaginary axis.  To make it a finite closed contour, you'll want to make that into a quarter-circle: from $0$ to some large $R$, then along a circular arc to $iR$, and back to $0$.

Comment: I have to multiply the result by 4,right?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is an even function... I would go from -infinity to infinity using the standard contours for that, and divide the result in two.

Comment: It is easier to integrate along the quarter of the circle,isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so.  If you do the quarter circle, you have two pieces to the contour; the edge of the circle and the line of the imaginary axis.  If you do the half-circle, you only have the edge of the circle.

Comment: On the other hand, this way you have two residues to compute rather than one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  I don't know what the residue is

Comment: Indeed.  That is not so bad, though.